# Отрисовка таблицы php из sql и вывод на веб-страницу

Tags: php, sql

[image: Описание необходимой таблицы]

Есть обработчик вывода расписания учебной группы. Необходимо структурировать полученные данные в таблицу, наподобие вышеуказанной. Напишите, пожалуйста, часть кода отрисовки, далее, думаю, мне должно быть понятно. Используемый обработчик:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Succesful</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require 'connect.php';
mysqli_set_charset($db_connect, 'utf8');
$group_number = $_REQUEST['group_number'];
$task_family = $_REQUEST['task_family'];
$week_day = $_REQUEST['week_day'];
$week_period = $_REQUEST['week_period'];
$task_lecture = $_REQUEST['task_lecture'];
$task_index = $_REQUEST['task_index'];
$sql_select = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `pisos` WHERE group_number LIKE '%$group_number%' AND (task_family LIKE '%$task_family%' OR task_family2 LIKE '%$task_family%') AND week_period LIKE '%$week_period%' AND week_day LIKE '%$week_day%' AND task_lecture LIKE '%$task_lecture%' AND task_index LIKE '%$task_index%'";
$result = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql_select);
$result_sum=$result;
$iter=0;
do
{
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM `pisos` WHERE group_number LIKE '%$group_number%' AND (task_family LIKE '%$task_family%' OR task_family2 LIKE '%$task_family%') AND (week_period LIKE '%$week_period%' or week_period LIKE '0') AND week_day LIKE '%$week_day%' AND task_lecture LIKE '%$task_lecture%' AND task_index LIKE '%$task_index%'";
$result = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql_select);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { print_r("<p>Номер группы: ".$row['group_number']."</p><p>ПАРА №: ".$row['task_index']." Чётность: ".$row['week_period']."</p><p>Начало: ".$row['task_start']." Конец: ".$row['task_finish']."</p><p>Дисциплина: ".$row['task_name']." ".$row['task_type']."</p><p>Аудитория: ".$row['task_lecture']."</p><p>Преподаватель: ".$row['task_family'].$row['task_family2']."</p><p>___________________</p>");
}
$iter++;
}
while ($iter<$result_sum);
$iter=0;
?>

<form method='post' action='allauthor.php'><b/>
<input id='submitread'  type='submit' value="Вернуться к поиску"><b/><b/>
</form>
<form method="post" action="https://site.ru">
<input id="submitback" type="submit" value="На главную">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если оооочень условно, только чтобы показать, то примерно так:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: 640kb
 * Date: 01/01/2020
 * Time: 02:47
 */

?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Table 640</title>
<body>
<table width="800" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
    <?php
    require 'connect.php';
    mysqli_set_charset($db_connect, 'utf8');
    $group_number = $_REQUEST['group_number'];
    $task_family = $_REQUEST['task_family'];
    $week_day = $_REQUEST['week_day'];
    $week_period = $_REQUEST['week_period'];
    $task_lecture = $_REQUEST['task_lecture'];
    $task_index = $_REQUEST['task_index'];
    $sql_select = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `pisos` WHERE group_number LIKE '%$group_number%' AND (task_family LIKE '%$task_family%' OR task_family2 LIKE '%$task_family%') AND week_period LIKE '%$week_period%' AND week_day LIKE '%$week_day%' AND task_lecture LIKE '%$task_lecture%' AND task_index LIKE '%$task_index%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql_select);
    $result_sum=$result;

    echo '<tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="' . $result_sum . '" valign="top" width="50px" style="vertical-align: middle">' . $week_day . '</td>
    </tr>';

    $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM `pisos` WHERE group_number LIKE '%$group_number%' AND (task_family LIKE '%$task_family%' OR task_family2 LIKE '%$task_family%') AND (week_period LIKE '%$week_period%' or week_period LIKE '0') AND week_day LIKE '%$week_day%' AND task_lecture LIKE '%$task_lecture%' AND task_index LIKE '%$task_index%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql_select);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr>
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="2" valign="top" width="70px" style="vertical-align: middle">' . $row['task_index'] . '</td>
        <td valign="top" width="70">' . $row['task_start'] . '<br>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" width="200px" style="text-align: center">' . $row['task_name'] . '<br>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">' . $row['task_finish'] . '<br>
        <td valign="top">' . $row['task_lecture'] . '<br>
        <td valign="top">' . $row['task_family'] . '<br>
    </tr>'; }?>
</table>
<form method='post' action='allauthor.php'><b/>
<input id='submitread'  type='submit' value="Вернуться к поиску"><b/><b/>
</form>
<form method="post" action="https://site.ru">
<input id="submitback" type="submit" value="На главную">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

НО!
 ***По-хорошему надо стили, показатели и ширину столбцов вывести отдельно в css
 проставить шорткаты вместо `<?php` (Не знаю просто прописаны они у вас в ini или нет.)
 Проверять наличие данных в БД, вдруг поле какое не пустое из $row и так далее. 
 Как и просили, это чисто для демонстрации отрисовки, надеюсь сможете уже адаптировать как необходимо.*** 
 Глаза слипаются, надеюсь ничего не упустил.

Comment: выдаёт ошибку:  Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in в 33 строчке. Если вырезать 
```
   echo '<tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
        <td colspan="1" rowspan="' . $result_sum . '" valign="top" width="50px" style="vertical-align: middle">' . $week_day . '</td>
    </tr>';
```
То криво, но выводит

Comment: И ещё интересует, как сделать полученную таблицу по центру, тег <center> не помогает

Comment: @Сергей Корягин, по поводу первого сообщения было такое предположение, а то как-то Вы смело написали $result_sum=$result; Надо обработать результат при помощи mysqli_fetch_array или вывести подсчёт количества через mysqi_num_rows($result), в запросе без count. А чтобы сделать таблицу по центру, задайте класс для table и в css выровнять либо вручную, либо через margin: auto;